Crontab created by www-data user not working
I have a python that creates a cron job in order to call another python script, but it's not working properly.
In the first python I have:
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user=True)
job = cron.new(command='/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/dev/alarm.py')
job.minute.every(1)
cron.write()

When I execute sudo crontab -u www-data -e I can see it as:
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/dev/alarm.py

But it's not executing this alarm.py script. If I try to execute the alarm.py script as www-data user I get error to import modules, because they were installed as user ubuntu.
I.E.:
$ sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/dev/alarm.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/dev/alarm.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pushover import Pushover
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pushover'

So I manually changed the www-data crontab to:
* * * * * ubuntu /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/dev/alarm.py

In order to execute as ubuntu user. But still not working.
Anything wrong here?
thanks.

You can't put a username in the www-user crontab file. Either put the original entry in the ubuntu crontab file, or put this in the system-wide /etc/crontab (or one of the files in /etc/cron.d).

I understand, but changing the crontab file to other place looks impossible since I'm using python-cron tool to generate the cron job. And manually changing it is not an option since I'll generate multiple times in a day.

One solution I've found was changing the apache2 user/group in /etc/apache2/envvars to ubuntu. Now it's working because it's writing the cron inside ubuntu user. I don't know how safe this is...
